# How can I omit left-side of contents first?

Tags: css

I'm making a menu like [this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DjdTY/), and I want to improve this like (when resizing the window):

- If `nav` do not have any blank on right side, then *omit* the left side
  `A  ...ohime sama > Ki ga tsuite ne ne > Mataseru nante rongai yo  B`
  `A  ...suite ne ne > Mataseru nante rongai yo  B`
- but do *not* omit `#currentstage`
  `A  ...> Mataseru nante rongai yo  B`
  `A  ...> Mataseru nante rong` (with horizontal scrollbar)

Can I make this HTML+CSS only?

EDIT: I mean, *[this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rhTz9/1/)* without Javascript. And though each of `a.button`'s width is fixed, `nav`'s width **isn't**. Its html is changable. So (I guess) media query won't be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in css identify the points at which the element has no space to show on the devise and specify what to do accordingly when such a width occurs below is an example of the common devise widths found and queried accordingly.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*put your css code here*/

#stage1{

} 
 }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bunos/1/edit)**

This can be done using css3 media queries. read more about it here: [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Here is one example how you need to do:

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    nav div {
        display: none;
     }
    #currentstage {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Hope you can do the same for other screen sizes